# conditional convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I apologize in advance for my English.

the question is:

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converge conditionally. prove that
> there's a sequence $\left(b_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that fulfills
> the condition $b_{n}\in\left\{ -1,1\right\} $
>
> and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}a_{n}$ diverge to minus infinity.

i managed to prove that if a series is conditionally convergent, then the series of positive and negative terms are both divergent, but couldn't get much after that.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you use $b_n=-\text{sign}(a_n)$, in which $\text{sign}(a_n)$ is the sign of $a_n$. If $a_n \geq 0$ the sign will be $+1$ (positive). If $a_n\leq 0$ the sign will be $-1$ (negative).

Note that $\text{sign}(a_n)a_n=|a_n|$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_na_n=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$$

As the sequence $a_n$ is conditionally convergent we know that the sum of absolute values diverges to $\infty$. Hence, we conclude divergence to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Elon_Sh Added explanation.

Comment: isn't it suppose to be the opposite for divergence to $-\infty$?

Comment: @Elon_Sh I corrected it to the negative version.

Comment: that's what i tried to do, couldn't figure out a way to prove it formally. is there a way to show that using the sequence its partial sums?

Comment: @Elon_Sh It directly follows from the definition of conditionally convergent.